# Rails custom project structure autoloading configs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoloader, zeitwerk

I have a standard app that contains of sub-apps that we will slowly migrate into separate gems. The main problem is that each sub-app basically has an almost identical schema and very similar business logic that sometimes is really pretty much the same.

Currently, as a first step, we created a subfolder in `lib/client` with a structure like a typical rails app.

As an example, a concern for a `ClientA` looks like this/

```
module Client
  module ClientA
    module Concerns
      module MyConcern
       ...
    end 
  end
end
```

This all works fine and gets autoloaded by Zeitwerk.

However, when I want to create an initializer in a Rails way, I don't want to wrap it inside modules and make a class around it and this is where I am getting `lib/clients/ClientA/config/initializers/custom_initializer.rb to define constant Clients::ClientA::Config::Initializers::CustomInitializer, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)`

This folder gets autoloaded like this

```
   config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
   config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/client/**/*)
```

Is there a way how to

- Blacklist the folder from being autoloaded by Zeitwerk?
- Load it using `require` or in any other way without wrapping it in modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [ignore parts of the project in zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#ignoring-parts-of-the-project) using `Loader#ignore`. You can [access rails zeitwerk autoloader](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#rails-autoloaders) via `Rails.autoloaders.main`.

So you should be able to add something like this to your `application.rb`:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join('lib/clients/*/config/initializers/*.rb'))
```

You'll then have to require them manually, maybe in an initializer in the main app directory. You could create a `config/initializers/clients.rb` with something like:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/clients/*/config/initializers/*.rb')].each do |filename|
  require filename
end
```